# XUnit is Not Executing Code Inside String Before Comparing Expected/Actual

Tags: c#, xunit

I have the following code with simple string interpolation:

```
public string CreateStyledGuestList(VolunteerDTO volunteerData)
{
  List<GuestContact> guestListWithLeaderIncluded = GetNewGuestListWithLeaderIncluded(volunteerData);

  string styledGuestList = 
    "<div style=\"margin-left: 40px\">"
    + "<br>" + guestListWithLeaderIncluded.Select(g => g.FirstName + " " + g.LastName)
    + "</div>";

  return styledGuestList;
}
```

When I test this method, I get the following (note that the code is shown, instead of the resulting string):

> ```
>                              ↓ (pos 35)
> ```
>
> Expected: ···gin-left: 40px">
> Leeroy Jenkins
>   Actual:   ···gin-left: 40px">
> System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectListIterator···
>                                    ↑ (pos 35)

The test itself:

```
[Fact]
public void ShouldCreateGuestListWithOnlyLeader()
{
  VolunteerDTO volunteerData = new VolunteerDTO();
  volunteerData.FirstName = "Leeroy";
  volunteerData.LastName = "Jenkins";
  volunteerData.Guests = new List<GuestContact>();

  string actual = _fixture.CreateStyledGuestList(volunteerData);
  string expected =  "<div style=\"margin-left: 40px\"><br>Leeroy Jenkins</div>";

  Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
}
```

Why is the string not being interpolated / how do I fix this?

Comment: Need to see what GetNewGuestListWithLeaderIncluded is doing. Looks like it's doint something to your DTO involving Linq, and it's not what you expected. (BTW, is that 'pos 35' stuff an exception? It's really not clear what it's about...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`guestListWithLeaderIncluded.Select(...)` will return an `IEnumerable<string>` and not a `string`

You need to join the strings to one string like:

```
... + string.Join("<br>", guestListWithLeaderIncluded.Select(...)) + ...
```